# Does QCA6174 driver in Linux support 64 bit in Kernel 5.4?

Tags: drivers, wireless

Could someone help me to understand if Linux Kernel 5.4 support QCA6174 chip with 64 bit mode? Could you please point me to right source code which has 64 bit support?

Thanks
Sudeep

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is supported, to check you can do `grep QCA6174 /proc/modules`

if the return is `ath10k_pci` then it is good

For the source code you can go to https://www.kernel.org/ the code source will be in the kernel source tree drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k